# Does closing the application stops all active BackgroundWorkers?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

Simple question, to repeat the title:

**Does closing the WinForms application stops all active BackgroundWorkers?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it does.

`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync` simply calls `BeginInvoke` on a internal delegate, which in turn queues the request to the `ThreadPool`. Since all `ThreadPool` threads are [background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx), yes, it will end when the application ends.

However, keep in mind that:

1. By "closing the WinForms application" I am presuming closing the *main `Form` instance* (that's generally the one passed to `Application.Run` in the `Program` class autogenerated by Visual Studio). If you have a child window with a background worker, it will not stop its `BackgroundWorker` automatically.
2. Letting a background thread be aborted on application exit is **not** the recommended way to end the thread, as you have no guarantees where it will be aborted. A much better way would be to signal the worker before closing, wait for it to finish gracefully, and then exit.

More info: [Delegate.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb.aspx), [MSDN on Thread Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx), [Thread.IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

The only way a thread can go on executing after your main (UI) thread has stopped is if it has been created explicitely, by creating a new Thread instance and setting the IsBackground to false. If you don't (or if you use the ThreadPool which spawns background threads -  or the BackgroundWorker which also uses the ThreadPool internally) your thread will be a background thread and will be terminated when the main thread ends.

Answer (score 6):

BackgroundWorker threads are background threads ([ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) threads), [which die when the application dies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.  I wrote this simple form, and closing the form exits the application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the application completely closes (as in nothing is preventing it from shutting down) your background workers will also be gone.

Comment: That's kind of a circular answer. If the background workers aren't stopped automatically when the app is closing, they will prevent the application from closing.

Answer (score 0):

Once the process is gone all associated threads are gone as well.

Comment: Except if their `IsBackground` property is set to `false`.

Comment: Which would prevent the process from terminating. So the answer holds ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just to make this answer simple:

When a process has closed, all of its threads have terminated. There's no question about this.

The question, as I interpret it, thus becomes:

> Will still-running `BackgroundWorker` instances prevent an application from closing?

The answer to *that* question is: No, they won't.

Answer (score -1):

I think yes. Because threads are associated with process and if the process is closed all threads has to end.