# Is it necessary to cancel Task inside of finalizer?

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection, task-parallel-library, cancellation

I have `viewModelA` and `viewA`. I run some time consuming operation in constructor of viewModelA:

```
public class ViewModelA
{
    Task task;
    CancellationTokenSource token;
    public viewModelA()
    {
       task = new Task(TimeConsumingOperation, token.Token);     
    }

    private void TimeConsumingMethod()
    {   
       //some time consuming operation
    }

    ~ViewModelA()
    {
       token.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Let's imagine that I run this application which consists just `viewA` and `viewModelA` and program starts some time-consuming operation(`TimeConsumingMethod()`) and *suddenly* I would like to **immediately** close the program, but I know that `TimeConsumingMethod()` **is still running.**

**So my question is should I cancel a Task inside of finalizer?** Or maybe  I just should not create a finalizer method cause finalizer should be called for unmanaged resources?

Comment: Ehh if you kill the application then wouldn't that kill the task? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687677/does-closing-the-application-stops-all-active-backgroundworkers

Comment: Finalizers are for releasing unmanaged resources.  You shouldn't be interacting with managed resources in the finalizer.

Comment: You should be making `viewModelA` disposable and you should cancel the task in there.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell yeap, you are right, but there is some important sentences in the end of the accepted answer  "A much better way would be to signal the worker before closing, wait for it to finish gracefully, and then exit."

Comment: @Downvoter It is really interesting for me what the reasons is to downvote?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why there is a downvote. This is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposal certainly seems like an abuse of the finalizer, at first glance. As noted, finalizers are typically for cleaning up unmanaged resources. More importantly, finalizers should not in fact be part of the contractual design of an object. They exist solely for the purpose of acting as a backstop for buggy code, i.e. to clean up resources when the client code has failed to do so explicitly (e.g. by calling `IDisposable.Dispose()`).

So the first thing I would look at is how *non*-buggy code should interact with your class. Is there in fact an `IDisposable` implementation? If not, then there also shouldn't be a finalizer. Do you feel strongly you need a finalizer? Then your class should implement `IDisposable` (or an equivalent), so that correct code can clean up the object efficiently.

Now, the second thing to look at is whether this task needs to be cancelled at all. What is it that you hope to accomplish by cancelling the task? Do you expect to need to cancel the task in a scenario *other* than exiting the process? How is the task itself implemented? Do you even start the task anywhere? These are all questions that are not addressed in your question, so there's no way for anyone to address them directly.

I will point out though that, assuming you call the `Start()` method at some point, the default implementation for the `Task` object is to execute the code using a thread pool thread. Thread pool threads are all background threads, and those threads are killed automatically when all of the foreground threads have exited, allowing the process itself to terminate normally.

So if all you're worried about is the state of the task when the process exits, *and* you are using the default implementation for the task, *and* the task can be safely interrupted at any time without corrupting data or leaving some temporary state active (e.g. a temporary file that should be deleted when the task completes), then I don't think you need to cancel the task explicitly.

On the other hand, if there is some reason to cancel the task explicitly, the right way to handle that is to provide a mechanism (e.g. implement `IDisposable` or something more explicit) that the client code can use to explicitly notify your object that it is no longer needed and should clean up. When the client code invokes this mechanism, then you can cancel the task.

In this case, you might want to implement a finalizer, but do so knowing that for correctly behaved client code, this finalizer will never be called. It's there only to protect against badly behaved code. It is also very important to understand that there's no guarantee at all that the finalizer will ever be called even for badly behaved code, and the most likely scenario for it to fail to be called is in fact when the process exits.

Finally, if you find you feel a finalizer is in fact required, I urge you to look at the [`SafeHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.110).aspx) class. This is a .NET class you can use as a base class for a helper object that will abstract the disposable nature of your task object. In that way, your own object need not implement a finalizer itself; instead, the `SafeHandle` subclass you implement will automatically address that need.

Comment: Thank you very much for so extensive and nice answer!:)